# Can `r` be used for multiple letters?

Tags: replace

## Background

I am new to vi/vim world and finished running the vimtutor several times.

## The setup

In the tutorial we learn several items to correct or edit lines of text.

- `r` to replace the letter the cursor is over
- `i`, `a`, `A` to jump into insert mode
- `ce`, `c2w`, `c<#><cmd>`, etc - will delete the <#> and enter insert mode.

## The question

Is their a way to use `r` to specific a number of characters to replace?

Similar to `c` I am looking for something like `2r` to replace the next 2 characters. Is this possible? Is their a way to do this with `c` that I just haven't figured out yet?

Comment: You can use `r` in visual mode to replace highlighted characters. So `<ctrl-v>2Erx` would replace all characters of the current and next word (including space in between) with x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 slightly different ways to do this.

- `R` will enter "Replace mode". This is like insert mode except each character overwrites the character currently under the cursor. For example

  ```
  testing
  ^ Cursor here
  ```

  and pressing `Rrunn<esc>` will change the text to

  ```
  running
     ^ Cursor here
  ```
- Using `c`. For example, if you want to change 2 characters, you could do `2cl` or `c2l` to delete two characters and enter insert mode. You could also use `2s` as `s` is a synonym for `cl`
- The `r` command can take a count, but this will only work if you want to use the same character. For example, if I have 3 double quotes, and I want to change them to 3 single quotes, I could put the cursor on the first one and type `3r'`. Note that `R` also takes a count. If you typed `3Rabc<esc>` it will replace the next 9 characters with `abcabcabc`.

Comment: ‘l’ seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you for the reply. And ‘s’ looks like a powerful command to start experimenting with.

Comment: @daniel Glad I could help! `s` is very powerful indeed. Note that `S` is a synonym for `cc`